# Detecting selected cell using SWTableViewCell

Tags: ios

I have implemented the SWTableView class from https://github.com/CEWendel/SWTableViewCell

It is working fine, but I don't know how to retrieve the value of the cell objects when clicking on the exposed buttons.

This is how am I getting the object values at cellForRowAtIndexPath method:

```
  NSString *date = [self stringValueOfDictionaryObject:(id)[[historialServicios objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"date"]];
```

I have added three buttons that are shown when the user swipes the cell.
What I need is to add button actions that have to get values of the selected row object. Mainly, I need to retrieve the string date when clicking on the button "More"

This is the didTriggerRightUtilityButtonWithIndex method.

```
- (void)swipeableTableViewCell:(SWTableViewCell *)cell didTriggerRightUtilityButtonWithIndex:(NSInteger)index {
    switch (index) {
        case 0:
        {
            // More button is pressed
            UIActionSheet *shareActionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Share" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Share on Facebook", @"Share on Twitter", nil];
            [shareActionSheet showInView:self.view];

            [cell hideUtilityButtonsAnimated:YES];


            break;
        }
        case 1:
        {
            // Other  button is pressed
            UIActionSheet *shareActionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Share" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Share on Facebook", @"Share on Twitter", nil];
            [shareActionSheet showInView:self.view];

            [cell hideUtilityButtonsAnimated:YES];


            break;
        }
        case 2:
        {
            // Delete button is pressed
            NSIndexPath *cellIndexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:cell];
            [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[cellIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationLeft];
            break;
        }
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it as follows:

```
   NSLog(@"INDEXPATH=%@",[self stringValueOfDictionaryObject:(id)[[historialServicios objectAtIndex:cellIndexPath.row]
```

Now I can retrieve any object value from the selected row...